# Можно ли конвертировать HTML + СSS в SVG или gif?

Tags: html, css, svg, анимация, gif

Есть прелоэдер свёрстаный на html и сss, с анимацией (@keyframes), можно ли его как то легко, желательно автоматически, с помощью какой нибудь программы,преобразовать в SVG или gif файл?

*Так же у прелоэдера есть прозрачность, и её нужно сохранить в SVG или gif*

Comment: в gif через видео снятое с экрана -  2 минуты

Comment: @Stranger in the Q, забыл уточнить, там ещё прозрачность есть, её нужно сохранить.

Comment: ну вы бы добавили сам прелоадер в вопрос было бы проще сказать

Comment: Я просто думал, что может уже есть что нибудь готовое, какая нибудь прога, которой можно было бы скормить html + css, а она бы вернула svg.

Comment: http://www.hiqpdf.com/demo/ConvertHtmlToSvg.aspx
Есть такой, но только html => svg.